# Option setting with custom binding for query UI accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, accordion

I´m having this jquery UI accordion that is populated with Tasks = ko.observableArray();
Tasks depend on a selected project (not included in the following code). Whenever I choose a new project, the list of tasks are updated through a ajax-call to the database. 
The following code provides all the data, also after a new project is chosen, but i´m unable to control the behaviour (settings) of my according.

This is my HTML w knockout:

```
<div id="accordion" data-bind="jqAccordion:{},template: {name: 'task-template',foreach: Tasks,afteradd: function(elem){$(elem).trigger('valueChanged');}}"></div> 

<script type="text/html" id="task-template">
     <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Task' + TaskId}" class="group">
          <h3><b><span data-bind="text: TaskId"></span>: <input name="TaskName" data-bind="value: TaskName  /></b></h3>
          <p>
             <label for="Description" >Description:</label><textarea name="Description" data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>
          </p>
     </div>
</script>
```

And the accordion script:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#accordion")
         .accordion({
            header: "> div > h3"
            , collapsible: true
            , active: false
            , heightStyle: "content"
              })
         .sortable({
                  axis: "y",
                  handle: "h3",
                  stop: function (event, ui) {
                      var items = [];
                      ui.item.siblings().andSelf().each(function () {
                          //compare data('index') and the real index
                          if ($(this).data('index') != $(this).index()) {
                              items.push(this.id);
                          }
                      });
                      // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
                      // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                      ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
                      if (items.length) $("#sekvens3").text(items.join(','));
                      ui.item.parent().trigger('stop');
                  }
         })
         .on('stop', function () {
                  $(this).siblings().andSelf().each(function (i) {
                      $(this).data('index', i);

                  });
          })
          .trigger('stop', function () {
                 alert("triggered");
          })
    };
});
</script>
```

This is the binding:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor();
        $(element).accordion(options);
        $(element).bind("valueChanged",function(){
           ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion.update(element,valueAccessor);
        });
    },
    update: function(element,valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor();
        $(element).accordion('destroy').accordion(options);
    }
};
```

Arrays and values are ok and updated, but the accordion cannot be collapsed and the collapsible-option is not working. It seems to me I should somehow pass the options (header, collapsible, active etc.) into the binding-function, but how?

Answer (score 1):

You're already passing in the binding options to the accordion plugin in your bindinghandler init function

```
var options = valueAccessor();
$(element).accordion(options);
```

So what ever parameters are passed into the binding will be passed to the accordion plugin

```
<div id="accordion" data-bind="jqAccordion: { 
                               header: "> div > h3",
                               collapsible: true,
                               active: false,
                               heightStyle: "content"
                            }"></div>
```

You could also consider adding logic to the init function to accomodate default values so you don't have to pass every parameter every time (warning: example code below isn't cross browser)

```
var options = valueAccessor();
options.collapsible = options.collapsible === undefined ? true : options.collapsible; 
options.active = options.active === undefined ? false : options.active;

$(element).accordion(options);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Shouldn´t the parameters passed in the div be comma separated?

Comment: They certainly should! Updated answer to include commas